# Lookup of dependent qualified names

Tags: c++, name-lookup, dependent-name, qualified-name

This program does not compile (`error: 'foo' is not a member of 'N'`):

```
namespace N {
//    void foo();
}

template<class T>
void template_func(T t) {
    N::foo(t);
}
```

But if we uncomment the declaration of `void foo();`, it compiles. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/oqdos6).

Both versions have an error. `foo` even if declared, takes no parameters. The following questions pose themselves.

- Why does one version compile, but not the other?
- Is there a rule in the C++ standard, that says something like this? "If the compiler is able to prove that no instantiations can be well-formed, it may (but is not required to) diagnose the error without instantiation."

My theory is the following (is it correct?). Inside `template_func` `N::foo` is a qualified name and a dependent name at the same time. Lookup of dependent names is postponed until the instantiation of the template. Looking up a name (if successful) results in tying the usage of the name to a declaration of that name. But this process consists of two steps (let's now consider only qualified names, that look like a function call):

1. Finding the name in the scope of the qualifier (in this example this means namespace `N`). This might find more than one name, since functions can be overloaded.
2. Checking whether the arguments can be passed to the found name(s). This includes finding a best match, if more than one `foo` is in `N`. This way the usage of `N::foo` is tied to an `N::foo` declaration.

Actually the first step can be done without instantiation. The compiler seems to do it, and if no `foo` is found, it diagnoses the error (which is optional to do). If at lease one `foo` is found it does not bother with further analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your analysis seems to be correct, and your code is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, regardless of whether `void foo();` is commented out or not.

The part of the standard you're looking for is:

> #### [`[temp.res.general]/6.1`](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#res.general-6.1)
>
> The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:
>
> — no valid specialization can be generated for a template ...